# Issues deciding on approach to create object

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I'm trying to decide what's the best approach to instantiate a particular class. Basically there are two use cases for it: instantiate it in order to save a new entry to the database and fetch an existing entry from the database (and maybe edit the fetched entry and save it back to the database).

The issue I'm having right now is that I can't decide which mechanism for instantiating that class and populating its fields to choose. Say I have this class

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

And here are the usecases. If you want to fetch a student for the database, the code looks something like:

```
Student student = MyLibrary.GetStudent(id);
```

And if you want to create a new student and add it to the database:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.FirstName = "James";
student.LastName = "Jackson";
// etc
MyLibrary.CreateStudent(student);
```

The massive issue with this approach is that all the setters are public and I absolutely do not want this. But at the same time I want the user to be able to populate most of the `Student` fields freely (maybe with the exception of `Id`.

I'm thinking the builder pattern could be employed in here. This way I can keep the setters private and force the user to create read-only students via the builders. However it then becomes really awkward if the user wants to update a field and save it to the database:

```
var student = MyLibrary.GetStudent(id);
var newStudent = new Student.Builder(id).FirstName("NewFirstName").LastName(student.LastName)...etc...Build();
MyLibrary.CreateStudent(newStudent);
```

Basically my only issue with the builder approach is that the code can get quite awkward and tedious if you want to update an existing entry. Some of the classes I have can have around 10 fields and it's not great having to copy 9 of the fields and update one. But it may be much nicer than having a class with public setters.

What other options do I have?

Comment: Can you clarify why you want your setters to be private?

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't just using constructor overloads or default parameters? Default parameters aren't usually a good idea, but they'd certainly give you what you seem to be looking for...

Comment: @Magus Because in most cases my models have around 10 fields. Telescoping constructors are not great in this scenario...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [**CQRS**](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)(Command Query Responsibility Segregation)

The idea is that what you save and what you load back and edit later is not the same object. This way you have control over what fields are private and what are public. What can be updated, and what can't.

In **CQRS** you have Command Model and Query Model. Command model is responsible for CREATE/UPDATE functionality, query model is responsible for fetching the data.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate how that is appropriate though?

Comment: And I don't see the need to separate the command & query models in my case. They are basically identical.

Comment: You said you want user to be able to freely assign the fields. That's your command model. You also want to protect the fields when entity is already in the database - that's your query model. So they are definitely not identical, and that's how CQRS applies :)

Comment: I see what you mean now. So if I want to update an existing `Student`, I have to fetch a `StudentQueryModel` first, copy all its fields into a `StudentCommandModel` and then save the `StudentCommandModel` back to the database. I don't think it brings any benefits over the builder approach mentioned in my question. In fact it adds more complexity. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I don't see how builder patterns solves your issue? All I see it makes code look way more complicated and adds an extra pass-through layer. You might want to read Martin Fowler's article that I linked in my answer.

Comment: My "issue" is with creating and populating instances of the model. The builder pattern at least uses the same model for reading and writing. CQRS requires two models. IMHO this approach is more complicated.

Comment: "at least uses the same model" - are you looking for a great design or simple solution for your application? If you think builder is simpler, use builder.

Answer (score 0):

I think a nonpublic `set` for "user editable" properties is just making work for yourself.

I'd leave them `public` (for changeable properties, i.e. not `Id`) and then either use the DAO-style `.Edit` and `.Update` state change methods (where attempting to change before calling `.Edit` throws a runtime error), or simply always allow changes and supply `.CommitChanges` to store them, similar to .NET `DataContext`.

This also allows something like:

```
LoadStudent(s);
s.Name="Harry";
if(UserConfirmsChanges(s))
  s.CommitChanges();
```

where the important bit I'm referring to is `UserConfirmsChanges` which can work with modified, but not saved, data simply.

If you really want something similar to the DAO way, but with compile-time read only properties before `.Edit`, you'll have to have different classes or otherwise duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the setter private then you have to use construction arguments to set the properties.

ie

```
public class Student
{
    public Student(string firstName, string lastName....
```

Even if you use an additional builder class it will still need to do this underneath. I wouldn't bother with one, unless you are publishing the class or need to enforce some complicated setup logic.

When you come to update an existing object, in the OOP world you would expect to be calling a method on your object which would modify the private properties in accordance with some business logic, rather than simply setting a data value.

ie

```
myStudent.MoveIntoAccomadation(myCollege);
```

rather than

```
myStudent.Address = myCollege.Address;
```

if you are just doing the latter then it suggests that you object is really just a data struct. There's nothing wrong with this, you could be apssing it to services as  DTO, or just moving it around databases etc

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your `Student` is a composite struct of related fields.

From my preliminary experience with these, I highly recommend trying to make these fully *immutable*, which is also what you seem to have in mind(?)

As for your concern wrt. Builder Pattern:

> Some of the classes I have can have around 10 fields and it's not
>   great having to copy 9 of the fields and update one.

You have to give your builder a ctor that takes a `Student`, then the Builder can copy an existing `Student` and you can change only the update fields.